# Trigger django-simpleJWT auth manually

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to repurpose [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) to authenticate in a completely different way (phone number and SMS validation code in two different requests). The thing is I have everything developed, but due to the tight integration of this auth system in the project I would have to trigger manually the TokenObtainPairView so the user still receives the token and is authenticated in the system.

Is there any way I can do that? I thought about triggering the view manually, but that wouldn't work since even if I customize the serializer for that view, I can't override standard username/password for the user (the user doesn't have a password and the username is random)

Any ideas on how to do this?

My current code is this:

```
class LoginResource(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        payload = json.loads(request.body)
        try:
            profile = UserProfile.objects.get(phone=payload.get('phone', ''))
            code = codegenerator()
            profile.authentication_code = code
            profile.save()
            # TODO: Send the generated code over SMS
            send_mail(
                    'Your authentication code',
                    'Your authentication code is: {}'.format(code),
                    settings.EMAIL_SEND_FROM,
                    (profile.email,),
                    fail_silently=False,
                )
            payload = {
                "status": "success"
            }
            return JsonResponse(payload, status=200, safe=False)
        except Exception as e:
            payload = {
                "status": "error",
                "message": "Unable to obtain the user: {}".format(e)
            }
            return JsonResponse(payload, status=500, safe=False)


class ValidateCodeAndLogin(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        payload = json.loads(request.body)
        try:
            profile = UserProfile.objects.get(phone=payload.get('phone', ''))
            code = payload.get('validation_code', 'INVALID')
            if code == profile.authentication_code:
                profile.validated = True
                profile.authentication_code = ''
                profile.save()
                #
                # TODO: Return the JWT token
                #
            else:
                payload = {
                    "status": "error",
                    "message": "Invalid authentication code"
                }
                return JsonResponse(payload, status=401, safe=False)

        except Exception as e:
            payload = {
                "status": "error",
                "message": "Unable to obtain the user: {}".format(e)
            }
            return JsonResponse(payload, status=500, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I haven't read the documentation completely and I was goign the wrong way. It is specified [here](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt#creating-tokens-manually) how to trigger the token generation manually, so I just had to do that.